# Invalid CSS after "...-padding: (math": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".div(100, 16) * 9);"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sass, scss-mixins, sass-loader

I try to use the vue-laravel-file-manager in my project. After I use `yarn run serve`, I get the error below.

https://github.com/alexusmai/vue-laravel-file-manager/

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                      7:25:34 PM

 error  in ./node_modules/laravel-file-manager/src/FileManager.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

$embed-padding: (math.div(100, 16) * 9);
                    ^
      Invalid CSS after "...-padding: (math": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".div(100, 16) * 9);"
      in  /node_modules/plyr/src/sass/types/video.scss (line 27, column 22)

 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/laravel-file-manager/src/FileManager.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& 4:14-363 15:3-20:5 16:22-371
 @ ./node_modules/laravel-file-manager/src/FileManager.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
 @ ./node_modules/laravel-file-manager/src/FileManager.vue
 @ ./node_modules/laravel-file-manager/src/init.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://10.0.2.15:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: I'm also getting this issue today on Plyr.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, replacing `"node-sass"` with `"sass"` fixed it for me.

This error probably occurs due to the depreciation of node-sass.